# How to speed up pandas read_sql for MySQL data using temp file?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have got solution for [Postgres](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimizing-pandas-read-sql-for-postgres-f31cd7f707ab), but I don't know how to achieve this functionality in MySQL?

```
import tempfile
import pandas


def read_sql_tmpfile(query, db_engine):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
        copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
           query=query, head="HEADER"
        )
        conn = db_engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpfile)
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        df = pandas.read_csv(tmpfile)
        return df
```

The problem here is that for PostgreSQL , the `db_engine` is created by using the library `psycopg2`. And for MySQL I can use pyodbc, sqlalchemy and mysql.connector. But any of these doesn't have the `copy_expert` method available.

Comment: You does not share any code, you just copied from the link. You must try something then ask StackOverflow.

Comment: I would like to know how you decide what to ask, when to ask and how to ask things in StackOverflow @Alper

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask